# Why does Couchbase use so much CPU?

Tags: couchbase

I have very recently installed Couchbase on my server, but it uses a lot of CPU and does a lot of disk IO. As you can see from the images below it is very clear when I installed Couchbase, as the CPU usage has sky-rocketed!

**CPU usage over 30 days**
[image: CPU usage over 30 days]

**CPU usage over the last 24 hours**
[image: CPU usage over the last 24 hours]

**Disk usage over 30 days**
[image: Disk usage over 30 days]

**Disk usage over the last 24 hours**
[image: Disk usage over the last 24 hours]

As you can see from the CPU usage I turned of Couchbase between 14:00 and 15:00 (and the CPU usage dropped to 0%). Then I turned it on again and connected a Scala web application to it (at which point the usage jumped up to 110%). This application had zero users and did absolutely nothing. It connected tot he Couchbase server and then waited for requests from clients). At 17:00 I turned it off and the CPU dropped down to 15% again. At 21:00 I turned on the application again and the CPU usage jumped up to 110% again.

What is Couchbase doing? The Scala application which uses Couchbase does absolutely nothing (below is a graph of the number of operations Couchbase does per seconds), but Couchbase still does continous disk IO and uses 110% CPU. Even with no applications connected to the Couchbase server it uses 15% CPU! How is this acceptable for a database?

**Couchbase operations per second over the last 24 hours**
[image: Couchbase operations per second over the last 24 hours]

Comment: From you data is unclear what's going on. If you can give us cbcollect_info then there's greater chance we'll be able to see something.

Comment: Agree with @alk
If it was also off from 1700 to 2100, why does the disk usage which you blame on it not slow during that period?  You may be jumping to conclusions.  What does top show?
..err, just noticed the age of this question.  Did you find a solution?  Answered?

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase has some processes running in the background to check the state of the cluster, document indexing and state the disk (to do some cleanup, compaction, ..).

This is why you see some activity in your database.

Comment: Occupying a significant amount of CPU cycles along with 300 IOPS just for "background work" seems kind of excessive. Can you elaborate a bit on how the activity can be identified and controlled (and possibly limited)? And why is a client's idle connection occupying an entire CPU core?

Comment: Is this actually such a problem? Agreed the usage seems high, but keep in mind that Linux will use as much CPU resource as it needs to. The fact that its using ~100% probably just means it has nothing better (read more important) to do.